# How to remove all duplicates from an iterable by attributes?

Tags: python, set

Given an iterable, e.g.

```
results = [ref_a, # references big object A
           ref_b, # references big object B
           ref_c, # references big object A
           ref_d, # references big object D
]
```

The references are each unique objects, but some reference the same (bigger) object.

I only want a set(or list) of references for unique objects.

My desired result is e.g.

```
custom_set = (ref_a,
              ref_b,
              ref_d,
)
```

**Remarks**

The Python builtin `set` is not applicable, as the objects from the input are all different. This means `set` would return all elements.

I cannot change the class definition for the references, so I cannot implement a custom cmp/hash function or similar.

It does not matter if the final result contains `ref_a` or `ref_c`.

The initial result is a combination of the results of different APIs, which act independently - this is also the reason that the combined list can have references to the same (big) object.

I cannot store the `result.reference` only, as after the filtering, I need to access other attributes of the `result`. If I'd only store `result.reference` I would have to instantiate the costly object.

Sorry for using `result` as the input parameter, but I do not want to change it afterwards, as the answers would not fit to the question any more. I will remember this for a future question.

Maybe `reference` was also not the best naming - it is more like a lightweight proxy object.

Comment: can you give a more *tangible* example?

Comment: Values for each ref var would be helpful. Right now I can't see what I'm working with.

Comment: I would also add that you are treading on dangerous waters here since your problem has more than 1 valid solutions.. Maybe consider storing the references instead?

Comment: Ev./Enrique - you are right - I tried to improve my question - I hope it is more clearer now. It is hard to come up with a more `tangible` example though, as it is really about lightweight proxy objects which keep a reference for more costly objects. For the latter I try to prevent instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, although you can solve this using `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

f = attrgetter('reference')
custom_set = set(next(x) for _, x in groupby(sorted(results, key=f), f))
```

Both `sorted` and `groupby` are stable, so `next(x)` is guaranteed to be the first element in `results` with a particular value of the `reference` attribute.

One drawback to this approach is that `sorted()` takes O(n lg n) time, compared to your O(n) traversal of the list.

You could also write your code as a (mostly) one-liner, though I wouldn't recommend it:

```
known = {}
custom_set = set(known.add(r.reference) and r for r in result if r.reference not in known)
```

`known.add(r.reference)` will always return `None`, so the value of the `and` expression will always be `r`, but the expression itself will only be evaluated if `r.reference` isn't already in `known`. The `and` expression is just a way to work the side effect of updating `known` into the generator expression.

Comment: chepner, thank you very much for your solutions. Having spent way too much time in really old Python code bases, I certainly guessed there were some solutions involving itertools / set or dict comprehensions, but personally I think both your solutions are quite hard to read. Maybe it is just me because I am not used to those kind of solutions. Thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution, but there must be a better/ more pythonic one.

```
known = set()
custom_set = set()
for result in results:
    if result.reference not in known:
       known.add(result.reference)
       custom_set.add(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
a=[]

for i in results:

    if i not in a:

        a.append(i)

print(a)
```

Comment: Monu, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, it does not apply to the question. The results/references are all different objects, but have a common attribute value (result.reference). With your code not a single object would be filtered out. It is more like a copy of the complete list. As others pointed out, I should improve my question.